# mod_rewrite to seo URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I use .htaccess to redirect a URL like

`http://sample.com/photos.php?cat=13&sort=most_recent&time=all_time`

to

`http://sample.com/photos/comedy`

Thank you.

Comment: How do you get `comedy` from `13`? If you say "from a database", you're not going to be able to do this using mod_rewrite very easily, since htaccess rules don't have any access to your database.

Comment: Actually from a database. Category id for the comedy is 13. Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: *"Any solution?"*, yes, write a php script, or add to `photos.php` so that it looks to see what the request was, and redirect the browser to the friendly looking URLs if the request was made for the one with query strings.

Comment: Hi thanks again. Do you have any sample code for this. I'm not in to this redirects that much. Short and sweet if i can access right category with /category name, It will be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need make the "cat" param as string (http://sample.com/photos.php?cat=comedy&sort=most_recent&time=all_time)
Then you can use this rule.

```
RewriteEngine on     
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ $1.php?cat=$2&sort=most_recent&time=all_time
```

(not tested)

Comment: Thank you. But I was able to do like that. What I waned to do is if the URL referring cat='id', then I wanted to rename id to a sting like that. So I can use SEO URLs. I don't want other parameters actually (http://sample.com/photos/13/Comedy/most_recent/all_time/) If the final url like http://sample.com/photos/Comedy, that is what i want.